# why there is blank plot of seaborn?

Tags: python, seaborn

```
fig, ax =plt.subplots(1,2)
sns.relplot(ax=ax[0], x='Date', y='Del. Net Value', hue='MG 5', kind='line', 
data=time_series_product)
sns.relplot(ax=ax[1], x='Date', y='Del. Net Value', hue='MG 5', kind='line', 
data=time_series_product1)
```

Very simple purpose: I just want to have these two plots side by side.
But the result:
[image]

I got blank plots and the figure size is so small. Is there any solution to change both figure size and remove the blank plots below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html) you'll see that relplot generates its own Figure instance and returns a `FacetGrid` object with the plot on it for further tweaking, so the `f,ax=` is a bit redundant. If you want the blank plots gone add `plt.close()` like so:

```
sns.relplot(ax=ax[0], x='Date', y='Del. Net Value', hue='MG 5', kind='line', 
data=time_series_product)
plt.close()
sns.relplot(ax=ax[1], x='Date', y='Del. Net Value', hue='MG 5', kind='line', 
data=time_series_product1)
plt.close()
```

I think that should work. But I would personally just say

```
#fig, ax =plt.subplots(1,2)
f1=sns.relplot(ax=ax[0], x='Date', y='Del. Net Value', hue='MG 5', kind='line', 
data=time_series_product)
f2=sns.relplot(ax=ax[1], x='Date', y='Del. Net Value', hue='MG 5', kind='line', 
data=time_series_product1)
```

and then manipulate `f1` and `f2`. I think the `f,ax` you've added is a bit confusing if you want to do stuff to the plot later.